# Zoom/scale page on load for users to be as wide see my images of wordpress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, zooming, scale, viewport

So I designed a website that is for 1024x768... A decision I made based on global stats showcasing this to be still the predominant resolution.

I myself zoom in and it looks great. I used a few tricks on some pictures they are higher res but scaled down if you zoom in they are not blury.

However... now anyone who opens and doesn't know how to zoom in will see a page that's tiny as more and more people are using higher resolution screens. Still having the users to zoom in is not right and I want to fix this...

Is there a way to scale the page upon opening for each user depending on their viewport?

How a user sees it now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBqiQ.jpg

How I view it and would like users to view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNTIF.png

The only stuff I could find relating to zooming and scaling was for images only...

---

ADDITIONAL EDIT:

Ok in response to the answer given to me to what was given to me did not work in firefox not sure about IE as I did not test it but it was exactly what i wanted!

```
$('body').css('zoom',$(window).width()/1200);
```

Any suggestions?

The problem I also run in to using this is with an iframe I have: I use this on an iframe page to load the forum and fit it in the content of the wordpress page . This code automaticaly resizes it and puts it on top.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj)
 {
   obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
   obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';                        
 }
 </script>

[iframe id="frmid" frameborder="0" padding="0" margin="0" onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this); window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" src="http://muslimbodybuilding.com/Forum/" scrolling="no"]
```

See screenshot in comment I could not post another link limits me...

======================

I've also run across another similar solution that works in Firefox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var currentWidth = jQuery(document.body).width();
    var targetWidth = 1100; // experiment for your self
    var scrollWidth = 0; // need to make it dynamic --- was 20
    // if the screen is not bigger than the target, then don't mess with zooming
    if (currentWidth > targetWidth) {
      if (typeof document.body.style.transform != "undefined")
        document.body.style.transform = currentWidth / targetWidth;
      else if (typeof document.body.style.MozTransform != "undefined") {
        document.body.style.MozTransformOrigin = "left top";
        document.body.style.MozTransform = 'scale(' + currentWidth / targetWidth + ')';
      }
      else if (typeof document.body.style.WebkitTransform != "undefined")
        document.body.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(' + currentWidth / targetWidth + ')';

      jQuery(document.body).width(targetWidth - scrollWidth);
   }
});
</script>
```

It zooms in the iframe too, however the facebook slider I have then gets pushed and moves around as I keep changing pages.

In chrome it still does not zoom the iframe with this method.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery (you can do it without jQuery but it makes the code much more succinct for cross-browser compatibility) you could do:

> $('body').css('zoom',$(window).width()/768);

This sets the zoom property of the body to the ratio by which the browser window is wider than your design. [Beware that not all browsers support css zoom](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/zoom).

However, this is really a bit of a nasty hack - the 'modern' way to do it is to use [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), to give a good experience whatever the width of the client browser.

Comment: Hey that worked! However the iframe I have stays tiny... and it only worked in chrome, in firefox did nothing?.. Any ideas? I don't want to do a responsive design, I find them ugly and restrictive, ironically... What I made works... just want the page to zoom in according to width and have all the contents zoomed in as if i was doing it with a regular browser soom and for it to work across browsers

Comment: Without the jquery zoom the page looks fine and the iframe dynamically resizes height which is what i wanted using: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj)
 {
   obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
   obj.style.width = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth + 'px';                        
 }
 </script>

Comment: This is the problem I run into now with the zoom working but iframe not zooming:
http://www.upl.co/uploads/iframeproblem.png

Comment: You'll need to run the same (or similar) code in the iframe too. Firefox isn't compatible with css zoom (See the link in my answer above)

Comment: Hey DanSingerman check out the solution I just posted in the edited question. What do you think and the problem I run into.

Comment: As I said in my original answer it is a bit of a hack, and not the 'right' way. If it doesn't easily work, I would suggest trying to use media queries to give a good result, rather than this approach.